# How should I assign each worksheet to its own variable?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import *

#wb1 is the unallocated pupils
wb1 = load_workbook('unallocated.xlsx')

#wb2 will be the final allocations
wb2 = Workbook()
wb2.save("allocations.xlsx")
wb2 = load_workbook('allocations.xlsx')
```

After that I need to find a way that allows me to map each worksheet in `wb1` to the name of the worksheet. So the end product should be something like ws1 = [name of sheet 1], ws2 = [name of sheet 2], and so on.

```
for sheet in wb1:
    sheet.title = wb1[sheet.title]
```

This does not work – it doesn't put a `str` around it and moreover it give the type error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Family guest/Desktop/CEP final project/CEP final proj.py", line 13, 
>     in <module>
>     sheet.title = wb1[sheet.title]
>   File "C:\Users\Family guest\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib
>       \site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\child.py", line 93, in title
>     m = INVALID_TITLE_REGEX.search(value)
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
> ```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted this:

```
for num, sheet in enumerate(wb1, 1):
    vars()["ws{}".format(num)] = sheet.title
```

To *construct* the names `ws1`, `ws2`, ..., we use the `.format()` method to append the string representation of the `num` number to the `"ws"` string.

To (indirectly) *create* variables with those names, we add them as keys to the  `vars()` dictionary.

(The built-in function `vars()` will give you the *updatable* dictionary of all used names, so you may add new items to them.

The built-in function `enumerate()` will give you something as list of pairs `(1, worksheet1)`, `(2, worksheet2)`, and so on.)

Comment: uh i dont think you understand what i want to do is get
ws1 = [name of first excel sheet]
ws2 = [name of second]

Comment: I dont really need the whole dictionary the assignment is more for some other functions needed by the openpyxl package

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the changes in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Better than create new names in your `for` loop is to create a *list* of names, e. g.

```
ws = [sheet.title for sheet in wb1]
```

(and the access them with index: `ws[0]`, `ws[1]`, and so on).

Comment: This no differrent to `wb.sheetnames`

Comment: So I'm sorry, I give up. I'm not able to help you while you will not help me (and probably others, too) understand what you want. E. g.: **I have a workbook with 3 sheets with names People, Things, Animals and I want to assign the string "People" to the variable ws1, string "Things" to variable ws2, and so on**. BTW, it is as how I understood your question. You motivation will be probably helpful, too.